# firebase crashlytics integration not working

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

[gradle dependcies image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQffv.png)Hi all i am trying to integrating to integrate firebase crashlytics in my android project.i am getting below error even before it is initilized.please help anyone if you know the solution .i am attaching the error screenshot as well as my grdale dependencies code.

my error code is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1
    Process: com.gps.core.autoforce, PID: 28406
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callTimeout(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; in class Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder' appears in /data/app/com.gps.core.autoforce-WP-jrbYDvbMdMiYvjhM1Bw==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.<clinit>(HttpRequest.java:46)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequestFactory.buildHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:43)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.AbstractSpiCall.getHttpRequest(AbstractSpiCall.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)`
```

Comment: Incomplete images of code aren't useful, please post code _as text_.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

PFB the error I got,

```
01-12 09:12:28.064   963  2672 E NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::acquire()
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime: Process: XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX, PID: 18199
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:85)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.<clinit>(HttpRequest.java:43)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequestFactory.buildHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:43)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.AbstractSpiCall.getHttpRequest(AbstractSpiCall.java:113)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:80)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-12 09:12:28.135 18199  3097 E AndroidRuntime:    at
```

Got resolved by adding below to andorid/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
```